# Removing Punctuations in a string in C using Switch case

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, switch-statement

Can someone please help me and tell what is wrong with my code. I made the solution using switch case and replace the punctuations with empty string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() 
{
    char st[50];
    int i;
    printf("ENter the string:\n");       
    gets(st);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(st);i++)
    {
        switch(st[i])
        {
            case '!':
            case '"':
            case '#':
            case '$':
            case '%':
            case '&':strcpy(st[i]," ");
                     break;
        }
        printf("String is:\n");
        puts(st);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why to use `strcpy` for a single character?

Comment: what about case else and the end of the switch? why not use OR logic, that is short could be an If statement.  Rusty on my C++, been looking at C# and its different.

Comment: `strcpy` will copy the blank and the NULL terminator into the location specified by src, which in your case is not even a good address. You should change: `strcpy(st[i]," ");` => `st[i] = ' ';`.. You should have a default case for your switch that just does a break.  Also, compile with warnings turned on as they would have informed you of your mistakes.

Comment: the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for many years and completely removed from the C language back at The C standard C11

Answer (score 1):

1. `strcpy(st[i]," ")` is wrong use `st[i]=' '`; *(strcpy is for copy strings , is case of single char direct assignment is the process )* .
2. `gets(st)` is now removed from `C` .It causes `buffer overflows` . Use `fgets()`. [Read more on gets() and fgets()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fgets-gets-c-language/)

Here can replace `gets()` using `fgets()` by :-

```
fgets(st,50,stdin);
```

Modified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char st[50];
    int i;
    printf("ENter the string:\n");
    fgets(st, 50, stdin);
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(st); i++)
    {
        switch (st[i])
        {
        case '!':
        case '"':
        case '#':
        case '$':
        case '%':
        case '&':
            st[i] = ' ';
            break;
        }
        printf("String is:\n");
        puts(st);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Recommended :- move `puts()` outside `for-loop`.

**Output :-**

```
ENter the string:
!hello#%worl$
String is:
 hello#%worl$

String is:
 hello#%worl$

String is:
 hello#%worl$

String is:
 hello#%worl$

String is:
 hello#%worl$

String is:
 hello#%worl$

String is:
 hello %worl$

String is:
 hello  worl$

String is:
 hello  worl$

String is:
 hello  worl$

String is:
 hello  worl$

String is:
 hello  worl$

String is:
 hello  worl 

String is:
 hello  worl
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < strlen(st); i++)` would call the `strlen()` N times, Each call costing N iterations - Making this code O(N*N).  Consider `for (i = 0; st[i]; i++)`.  Still the output print time swamps any such improvement.

Comment: PS- You have a typo I can't fix because it's less than six characters. You say "fegts()" instead of "fgets()" -- "gets(st) is now removed from C .It causes buffer overflows . Use fegts(). Read more on gets() and fgets()"

Comment: @torstenvl thanks for that notification. I have changed.

Answer (score 0):

" " is a space.  I don't think this is your intended behavior.  Use another buffer to make a copy.  For example,

```
 #include<stdio.h>
        #include<string.h>
        int main() 
        {
            char sta[50];
            char stb[50];
            int i,j;
            printf("ENter the string:\n");       
            gets(sta);
            for(i=0,j=0;i<strlen(sta);i++)
            {
                switch(st[sta])
                {
                    case '!':
                    case '"':
                    case '#':
                    case '$':
                    case '%':
                    case '&': break;
                    default: 
                             stb[j++]=sta[i];
                             break;
                }
                stb[j] = (char)0; // C str termination...
                printf("String is:\n");
                puts(stb);
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Close.  `' '` is a _space_.  `" "` is a _string literal_.

Comment: This answer builds `stb[]` with punctuation characters, not with letters.

Comment: Sorry I missed something. Editing.

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. eliminates the 'magic' numbers
3. properly replaces the listed punctuation marks with a space
4. only prints the result once
5. uses the 'valid' function `fgets()` rather than the (currently) nonexistent `gets()` function
6. avoid comparing signed and unsigned values
7. limits the scope of the variable `i`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 50

int main( void ) 
{
    char st[ MAX_STR_LEN + 1 ];

    printf("ENter the string, max 50 characters\n");       
    fgets( st, sizeof( st ), stdin );

    for( size_t i=0;i<strlen(st);i++)
    {
        switch(st[i])
        {
            case '!':
            case '"':
            case '#':
            case '$':
            case '%':
            case '&':
                st[i] = ' ';
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    printf( "Modified String is:\n %s\n", st );
    return 0;
}
```